# focus-trap-react error when testing with vitest and jsdom

Tags: reactjs, mocking, focus, jsdom, vitest

I am having the following error when trying to test components with vitest running js-dom environment that use `focus-trap-react` .

`Error: Your focus-trap must have at least one container with at least one tabbable node in it at all times`

This is a link to the documentation of `focus-trap-react`, where they explain how to fix that issue using mocks with jest https://github.com/focus-trap/tabbable#testing-in-jsdom.

With my previous jest setup I had it running like in that exact way, but am unable to make it work in vitest. Maybe it has something to do with vitest not recognizing the `__mocks__` folder?

Edit: Github Issue - https://github.com/focus-trap/focus-trap-react/issues/1002

Comment: Provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @LinDu In this Github Issue the problem is explained better and the maintainer suggested a fix https://github.com/focus-trap/focus-trap-react/issues/1002